# Android 12 Restrict My interactions with my app's activities

Tags: android, package, android-12

Recently I have Noticed Some other apps interact my splash activity with out permission
I used   android:exported="false" but my app can't start by android system

I want to restrict this activity to be accessible only to android system

Thanks

Comment: "I want to restrict this activity to be accessible only to android system" -- an app launcher is itself an app; it is not part of "android system". If you prevent app launchers from starting your app, it is unclear how you expect users to start your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you have any idea how to prevent from others to interact my activity ?

Comment: Again: an app launcher is part of "others". You might want to explain, **in detail**, how you want users to start your app, if they cannot start it from the app launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks Really Appreciate your  reply.  my point is that so other app interacting my splash activity when exported=true  , so is there any other way to prevent them

Comment: @CommonsWare could app start with xml and service only with no activity

Comment: How can I limit any "other" applications, more specifically a malicious app, can launch my activity with an android:exported:="true", as this is why I would set the value to false. I tried setting it to false, but then I couldn't even run the app on android 12! I guess it should always be true on the launch activity? and I shouldn't be neurotic about other apps maliciously starting my app..